# Parsing error trying to add TypeScript to useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to understand how to use TypeScript with the useReducer hook. Here is a simple counter with regular JavaScript:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "+":
      return { ...state, no: state.no + 1}
    case "-":
      return { ...state, no: state.no - 1}
    default:
      throw new Error("All conditions missed");
  }
}

function App() {

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {no: 1})

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{state.no}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>dispatch({type: "-"})}>-</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>dispatch({type: "+"})}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-austin-eog2p

I've tried adding types but I get a parsing error:

```
interface IState {
  no: string;
}

function reducer(state: IState[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "+":
      return { ...state, no: state.no + 1}
    case "-":
      return { ...state, no: state.no - 1}
    default:
      throw new Error("All conditions missed");
  }
}

function App() {

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {no: 1}: IState[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{state.no}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>dispatch({type: "-"})}>-</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>dispatch({type: "+"})}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-forest-1gp88

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818026/usecontext-and-usereducer-in-typescript/71369632#71369632

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the signature for `useReducer()` is

```js
type Reducer<S, A> = (prevState: S, action: A) => S;
type ReducerState<R extends Reducer<any, any>> = R extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never;
type ReducerAction<R extends Reducer<any, any>> = R extends Reducer<any, infer A> ? A : never;
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
function useReducer<R extends Reducer<any, any>>(
  reducer: R,
  initialState: ReducerState<R>,
  initializer?: undefined,
): [ReducerState<R>, Dispatch<ReducerAction<R>>];
```

It looks like

```js
interface IState {
  no: number;
}

const reducer: React.Reducer<IState, any> = (state: IState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "+":
      return { ...state, no: state.no + 1 };
    case "-":
      return { ...state, no: state.no - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error("All conditions missed");
  }
};

// ...
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, { no: 1 });
```

parses, typechecks and runs fine – differences to your version:

- `no` in the interface is a number (required so the arithmetics within the reducer make sense, and the initial state).
- The reducer is an explicitly typed arrow function.

Comment: Does the reducer need to be an arrow function? I cant get it working if it's not: function reducer: React.Reducer<IState, any> (state, action) {

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to explicitly type a named function. :D

Comment: This is the right answer if you want to use TypeScript and useReducer!