# useContext and useReducer in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to **typescript** and I was implementing react useContext and useReducer. I was following a tutorial but im getting an error of `Parameter 'action' implicitly has an 'any' type.` In my reducer function.

**reducer function**

```
function reducer(state, action) { // error Parameter 'action' implicitly has an 'any' type.
     return { count: state.count + 1 }
}
```

**CountProvider**

```
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    count: 0
   })
```

Comment: You are using typescript. You should define types to your variables

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the type of action as any or do it by generic form. In case you want to structure action you could create an interface.

```
function reducer(state, action: { [key: string]: string|number }) { // error Parameter 'action' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    return { count: state.count + 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to type your acrion creators properly:

**Actions.ts**

```js
export const increment = (
  background: string
): {
  type: "INCREMENT";
  payload: {
    background: string;
  };
} => ({
  type: "INCREMENT",
  payload: {
    background
  }
});

export const decrement = (
  background: string
): {
  type: "DECREMENT";
  payload: {
    background: string;
  };
} => ({
  type: "DECREMENT",
  payload: {
    background
  }
});

export type Action =
  | ReturnType<typeof increment>
  | ReturnType<typeof increment>;
```

Then in your reducer you should import the type for your actions:

**Reducer.ts**

```js
import type { Action } from "./actions";

export const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

export type Store = typeof initialState;

export const reducer = (state: Store, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And lastly for typing your `useReducer` hook anywhere in your app:

**CountProvider**

```js
import type { Store } from "./context/reducer";
import type { Action } from "./context/actions";

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<React.Reducer<Store, Action>>(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );
```

You can read more about this here: [Elegantly type React’s useReducer and Context API with discriminated union of Typescript](https://medium.com/@mohsentaleb/elegantly-type-reacts-usereducer-and-context-api-with-discriminated-union-of-typescript-855ff475cafe)